# How to add multiple values in On demand settings- Spotfire to filter for specific data?

Tags: database, spotfire

I have been trying to figure out a way to get data for multiple string values through on demand settings via an information link in spotfire. 
Currently I use an excel file to import the table into spotfire and use that table's values to filter for what I need. But since this is cumbersome, I need someway to be able to pull data by just entering values in an input box and refreshing. Maybe I haven't found the correct separator yet. Can anyone please advise. My information link is fetching data from a SQL database and i need to define the tags to fetch the values.

[See this image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3328.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to rephrase it. Please describe better what do you have now, and also explain with a bit more details what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is very large, and you want to limit a single column based on a list of possible values, this is the methodology I have been using, which I have found works at generally reasonable speeds for lists with up to about 50,000 values:

1. Create a large Input Field (Data Type String).
2. Create a button that will "Load List", with a script that will parse it (allowing the user to separate by spaces, commas, tabs, or new lines) and put it into a new Property (also Data Type String).  In my example below, I reused the same bit of code for multiple data sets, so I had two script parameters, both Type String, one named PreList and referencing the Property for the Input field and one named PostList, referencing the Property that will be passed to our Information Link.

Script:

```
strVals = Document.Properties[PreList]

lst = ""

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
for letter in strVals:
    if y == 1:
        if letter == " ":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == ",":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "\n":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "\r":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == "'":
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == '"':
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
        elif letter == '\t':
            lst = lst + strVals[x:z] + ", "
            y = 0
    else:
        if letter <> " " and letter <> "," and letter <> "\n" and letter <> "\r" and letter <> "'" and letter <> '"' and letter <> "\t":
            #print letter
            x = z
            y = 1
    z += 1
if y == 1:
    lst = lst + strVals[x:z] 

print lst

Document.Properties[PostList] = lst
```

3. Our Information Link is set to Load Automatically, which means it will run after the user hits the Load List button.

The Information Link itself will reference a stored procedure which will ALSO parse the list it was just passed.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_ProcedureName
@UserID as varchar(max) , @SearchColumn as varchar(max)   = NULL 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @SQL as varchar(max) 
    declare @tSearchColumn as varchar(max) 

if @UserID <> ''        
BEGIN
delete [UserList]   where UserID = @UserID 
END

if @UserID <> '' and len(@SearchColumn) > 1 
begin 

     while len(@SearchColumn) > 0  
      begin 
            set @tSearchColumn = '' 
            if CHARINDEX(',',  @SearchColumn) = 0 
            begin 
               set @tSearchColumn =   @SearchColumn  
               set @SearchColumn = replace(@SearchColumn,@tSearchColumn,'') 
            end  
            if CHARINDEX(',',  @SearchColumn) <> 0 
            begin 
               set @tSearchColumn =  substring(@SearchColumn, 1 , CHARINDEX(',',  @SearchColumn)  - 1 )  
               set @SearchColumn = replace(@SearchColumn, @tSearchColumn + ',', '' )
            end 
     if len(@tSearchColumn) > 0 
     begin 

          insert into [UserList] 
            ([UserID]
                ,[SearchColumn]
                ,[LoadDate]) 
            (select  @UserID , replace(replace(@tSearchColumn,'''',''),' ',''), 2 , getdate() 
            where not exists (select * from UserList where [SearchColumn] = replace(replace(@tSearchColumn,'''',''),' ','')
            and [UserID] = @UserID )
            )

      end 

      end 

end


 select dt.* 
  from UserList ul join DesiredTable dt on ul.[SearchColumn] = dt.[SearchColumn]
  where [UserID] = @UserID


END
```

You can use a temp table if you prefer, but I was storing data into an instantiated table so I could check values later if necessary.